# Azure AD OAuth Client credentials flow access control

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Azure AD OAuth2 authorization, to secure my Web API. Now i need to support two OAuth2 scenarios(flows) -

1. Web application accessing the Web API, and the API based on the user's role will serve a resource. 
   This is the achieved using authorize oauth flow, and access control is done using Authorize[Role="Read"] attributes
2. A daemon(console) application accessing the same Web API. Though i am able to get a token by using the client credentials oauth flow, but i am not able to figure how to manage access to the daemon process

Once the token is issues the console can literally access any of the API methods.

Scope - when grant_type is "client_credentials" scope is not a parameter to /token endpoint
Role - Cant use it as this is associated with user

Can somebody please suggest, how we can do access control in client credentials flow ? And how i can cater both requirement 1 and 2 at the same time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define "roles" for both the users and the applications in your API's manifest in Azure AD.

Application roles are actually application permissions if you are wondering.

So you can have something like this in your API manifest (other properties removed for clarity):

```
{
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "Read all things",
      "id": "32028ccd-3212-4f39-3212-beabd6787d81",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Allow the application to read all things as itself.",
      "value": "Things.Read.All"
    },
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Read things",
      "id": "ef8d02ff-eee1-6745-9387-96587c358783",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Allow the user to read things.",
      "value": "Things.Read"
    }
  ]
}
```

So we are defining a role that allows only applications as its members. It's an application permission. The other is a role that can be given to users and groups.

You can then give users the Read things role, and the daemon console app the Read all things application permission. And you achieve both scenarios :)

You add the role to users/groups by going to Enterprise applications->Your API->Users and groups->Add user. Select the users/groups you want and then select a role for them (if you have only one it will be pre-selected).

[image: After adding the role, the user will show up in the list]

You add the application permission by finding the other application's App Registration->Required permissions->Add->Find your API->Select->Check the application permission you defined earlier from the list. Then you can press the Grant Permissions button to grant the app role.

[image: Permissions required by the Web App on the API]

You then get the value in the roles claim for either scenario.

So the *roles* claim will look like this in the first scenario:

```
"roles": [
    "Things.Read"
  ],
```

and like this in the second scenario:

```
"roles": [
    "Things.Read.All"
  ],
```

Comment: This will work in scenario 1, but how does this work client credentials flow ? Assuming i have one client application which should have "read" access and another one need "write" access where do i specify the mapping? Is there a way we can define this access in azure portal ? or can the client request for this read/write permission in the token request ?

Comment: The token you get back with client credentials should include the role, after you add the application permission to the console app in Azure AD and grant it.

Comment: Just to make sure this works like I remember I tested this. In both tokens you get a roles array, which contains the value defined in the role. So either Things.Read or Things.Read.All in this case. :)

Comment: "after you add the application permission to the console app in Azure AD and grant it". Can you please explain a bit on this. This is were i am struggling. I dont seem to have the option to grant a role to the console application in azure portal. Am i missing something ? It only lists the permissions listed in oauth2permissions, not the ones in approles

Comment: Hmm, if you define it as an app role in the manifest (with allowed member type Application), it should show up under app permissions when you go to the Required permissions in your Web App project.

Comment: It is not showing up the list of approles under required permissions. It only shows the list of oauth2permissions

Comment: So it does not look like in my post? Check the photo I added. Azure AD might be in a slow mood. Sometimes stuff gets stuck and you just have to wait a moment. Double-check your API's manifest and then check again. You can try a different browser too to bypass some caches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153242/discussion-between-anoop-and-juunas).

Comment: Though i have defined the appRoles, i dont see a "Application permissions" section, i could see only "delegated permissions" section. Is it viewable only to admin ?

Comment: Ahh... Your app might be a native app! They don't get app permissions since they can't keep secrets.

Comment: You'll need to make it a web app/api to use client credentials flow essentially.

Comment: The second parameter for the client credential should be a client secret/"key", it's not a GUID.

Comment: @junnas yes, that was a typo. i just want to show the jwt structure. Any thoughts on why the roles are not coming through in the jwt?

Comment: If you have given the app permission in the console app and *granted it*, then it should show up. No reason not to.

Comment: I have given the app permission in the console app. But what you mean by "granted it"? Do i need to click on "Grant Permissions" option in azure portal ?

Comment: Yes. Adding the app permission only says that this app would like to do this. It still requires admin approval for it to actually get the role assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get application role as you mentioned with token you get at Client side. But at server side (protected API side), there is no way to see Roles claims to authorize.

With User/Roles, you can create a mapping between Users and roles defined in Manifest file. So UI and API will know user roles to authorize.

With App/Roles, there is no way on Azure portal to create a mapping clientId/clientSecret to AppRole defined in Manifest.